# Custom Fields Only From Sharepoint List

Tags: c#, sharepoint, splist

Is it possible to loop through field collection of a sharepoint list and retrieve only our custom fields and not the sharepoint built-in fields.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost/"))
{
   using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
   {
       SPList list = web.Lists["My List"];
       foreach (SPField field in list.Fields)
       {
           //We also get sharepoint built-in column here. And we don't want that, just our
           //custom created fields.
       }
   }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Check if the field is a built-in field: `SPBuiltInFieldId.Contains(field.Id)`
2. Check on the [SPField.SourceId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.sourceid.aspx) (from MSDN):

> Gets either the namespace that defines a built-in field or, if it a custom field, the GUID that identifies the list or Web site where it was created.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a contrived (and currently untested) way:

```
string fieldTypeClass = field.FieldTypeDefinition.FieldTypeClass;

if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldTypeClass) || fieldTypeClass.StartsWith("Microsoft.SharePoint"))) {
//Only custom fields here
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if its really what you're looking for, of if LINQ is still "smiled upon" by .net digirati, [but using LINQ to Sharepoint might work for you.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535491.aspx#Y912)