# Sharepoint: Get form fields' display names from list

Tags: sharepoint, field

I am trying to extract the field names from a list, but only those that are normally displayed in the edit/view-form. However, it is turning out to be more difficult than first assumed.

Filtering fields by simply not taking those with `SPField.Hidden == true` still yields a lot of fields that are not relevant in this context. A standard document library yields this result as example:

```
FileLeafRef, Title, CaseID, DocID, Finalized, Related, RegistrationDate, ItemSelectField,
ExtendedDocIcon, CaseRecordNumber, Local_x0020_Attachment, ID, ContentType, Created,
Author, Modified, Editor, _CopySource, CheckoutUser, _CheckinComment, LinkFilenameNoMenu,
LinkFilename, FileSizeDisplay, Edit, _UIVersionString, ParentVersionString, ParentLeafName
```

I have taken the internal names because I have a danish localized version of Sharepoint, but you get the idea. In the above Title, CaseID, DocID and LinkFilename and perhaps some more fields will be relevant - one thing is for sure, less than half of these fields are displayed when you view the item or insert a new one.

I tried the `SPField.ShowIn*` (DisplayForm, EditForm, etc.) but they're all set to null or false for all the fields.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[Custom Fields Only From Sharepoint List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340746/custom-fields-only-from-sharepoint-list/5340866#5340866)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Hidden, try taking out Fields where:

- ReadOnly is `true`.
- Type is `Computed`
- Group is `_Hidden`

Comment: "ReadOnly is true" and "Type is Computed" should not be missed, because there are fields that are typically shown in property dialog box.